# NPM Google Spreadsheets Error: Each row must be an object or an array

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to add rows to a Google Spreadsheet after pulling from an API. Google Spreadsheet treats rows as objects, where the header is the key and that header's value is the property. Multiple rows are grouped in an array of objects (see more `[here][1]`). This is what I believe my code is doing, as it returns an array of dimensions and metrics objects. Perhaps Google Spreadsheets is having trouble because it appears to be nested (one layer for dimension, a second for profile id, reporting period ; one layer for metrics, a second for impressions and reactions.

One example of what's returned is here:
`{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-29"},"metrics":{"impressions":1792,"reactions":0}}`

**Can you please help me how I can add these to a Google Spreadsheet?**

````
const Sheet = require("./sheet.js");

fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + username,
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    filters: [
      "customer_profile_id.eq(3888890, 3888895, 3888919, 4205312, 4333025, 4401415, 4527629, 4540079, 4556340)",
      "reporting_period.in(2021-01-01...2021-05-01)",
    ],
    metrics: ["impressions", "reactions"],
    page: 1,
  }),
})
  .then(function (res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(stringData);
    console.log(arr);
    runIt(arr);
  });

async function runIt(arr) {
  const sheet = new Sheet();
  await sheet.load();
  await sheet.addRows(arr);
}```

// Which logs:

```[{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-29"},"metrics":{"impressions":1792,"reactions":0}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-30"},"metrics":{"impressions":2142,"reactions":2}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-31"},"metrics":{"impressions":1427,"reactions":1}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-02-01"},"metrics":{"impressions":1446,"reactions":0}}],"paging":{"current_page":1,"total_pages":2}}'```


  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet
````

Comment: I think that your `Which logs:` of `[{"dimensions":{,,,},{"dimensions":{,,,},,,],"paging":{"current_page":1,"total_pages":2}}'` is not complete. So I cannot understand about your sample input value. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the sample value of `arr`? And also, can you provide the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: `[{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-29"},"metrics":{"impressions":1792,"reactions":0}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-30"},"metrics":{"impressions":2142,"reactions":2}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-31"},"metrics":{"impressions":1427,"reactions":1}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-02-01"},"metrics":{"impressions":1446,"reactions":0}}]`

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Tanaike. I've pasted shortened version of the response above. As I've worked with Google Spreadsheets before, where each row is an object with the format {column header: cell value}. However, my hypothesis is that this nested object confuses the headers of the Google Spreadsheet because its likely expecting simply "customer_profile_id" and "reporting_period.by(day)", for example, in order to place into headers.`{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-29"},"metrics":{"impressions":1792,"reactions":0}}`

Comment: Is there a way to automatically remove the "dimensions" and "metrics" umbrella properties from this object? Keeping just "customer_profile_id", "reporting_period.by(day)", "impressions" and "reactions" fields?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to put the following values to Google Spreadsheet.

  ```
    [{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-29"},"metrics":{"impressions":1792,"reactions":0}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-30"},"metrics":{"impressions":2142,"reactions":2}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-31"},"metrics":{"impressions":1427,"reactions":1}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-02-01"},"metrics":{"impressions":1446,"reactions":0}}]
  ```
- Your header row is `customer_profile_id`, `reporting_period.by(day)`, `impressions` and `reactions`.

  - In this case, these values are put in the cells "A1:D1".
- You want to achieve this using [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet).
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I think that at first, it is required to create an array for putting to Spreadsheet from above values.
- Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail of `const Sheet = require("./sheet.js");`. So in this answer, "google-spreadsheet" is directly used. So please modify it for your actual situation.

#### Sample script:

**Before you use this script, please put the values of `customer_profile_id`, `reporting_period.by(day)`, `impressions` and `reactions` to the cells of "A1:D1". By this, the following script works. When the header row is not used, the values are not put. Please be careful this.**

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");
const creds = require("###JSON file of your service account###");

async function sample() {
  const values = [{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-29"},"metrics":{"impressions":1792,"reactions":0}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-30"},"metrics":{"impressions":2142,"reactions":2}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-01-31"},"metrics":{"impressions":1427,"reactions":1}},{"dimensions":{"customer_profile_id":"4205312","reporting_period.by(day)":"2021-02-01"},"metrics":{"impressions":1446,"reactions":0}}];

  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet("###"); // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
  await doc.loadInfo();
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // In this sample, the values are put to the 1st sheet of Google Spreadsheet.

  // Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  const rows = values.map((o) => Object.values(o).reduce((oo, e) => Object.assign(oo, e), {}));

  // Put the created array to Spreadsheet.
  await sheet.addRows(rows);
}

sample();
```

- In this sample script, your sample values are used. So, please modify it for your actual situation.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- From your replying, unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the output situation you expect. So in this answer, I used the values of `customer_profile_id`, `reporting_period.by(day)`, `impressions` and `reactions` as the header row. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [google-spreadsheet](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/)

Comment: this worked very well thank you so much. I've accepted your answer - please let me know how else I can support your profile. Very professional explanation!

Comment: @Conner Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm, glad your issue was resolved. From your question, I could also study. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hello @tanaike, I was wondering if you could explain this line of code: `const rows = values.map((o) => Object.values(o).reduce((oo, e) => Object.assign(oo, e), {}));` I am familiar with reduce functions in terms of summing numbers but am unsure how these abstract variables (oo, e) are contributing to the array

Comment: @Conner About `const rows = values.map((o) => Object.values(o).reduce((oo, e) => Object.assign(oo, e), {}));`, in this case, `values.map` returns each element of the array. And, at `Object.values(o).reduce`, each object `dimensions` and `metrics` are merged as an object and return it. If this was not useful, I apologize.